# Should quest mods be installed ASAP?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

There are multiple quest mods that I don't plan on playing through until level 20-ish. These mods are completely separate from the vanilla Skyrim quests.

Would installing them later cause conflicts? Should I install them before I make a new character?

Some of these mods include Summerset Isles, Falskaar, Undeath, and The Wheel of Lull.

Another mod I am looking at is Helgan Reborn. The mod pages indicates that I should not install it at the beginning of a new game, but rather only after a specific condition has met. For these mods, should I install them ASAP?

Answer (score 6):

I would say that install all the mods before starting a new game, except the ones who specifically say that you should install them at different point, like that Helgan reborn. Check out the respective mod readme and/or instruction files to ensure functionality.
It is always a slight gamble if the mod functions correctly. Some mods may not even function if you do not start a new game to begin with them.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually safest to install mods before you start playing on your character, but it's generally safe to install mods mid-playthrough as well. It will highly depend on the mod itself and **reading the mod author's installation instructions is always important.** Try to follow them.

In some cases, you cannot access a required piece of vanilla content due to a mod overwriting it, so you'll need to do that first in vanilla. But cases like that are rare and often caused by poor mod design.